# Laravel how to load Font Awesome in subdirectory

Tags: laravel, font-awesome

When my app was within the `public_html` directory, Font Awesome loaded adequately, but it no longer worked as soon as I moved the app to `public_html/app`. Inspecting the network tab, I can see a `404` message in response to that resource (font-awesome) request because my application is looking for the Font Awesome in a URI which doesn't exist.

Where it looks for Font Awesome:

`http://example.com/fonts/vendor/font-awesome/fontawesome-webfont.woff?fee66e712a8a08eef5805a46892932ad`

Where I expect it to look:

`http://example.com/app/fonts/vendor/font-awesome/fontawesome-webfont.woff?fee66e712a8a08eef5805a46892932ad`

Comment: where you place your font-awesome js file?

Comment: I installed it using npm

Comment: npm? how? sorry because i never use npm to include script.

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden Sorry I don't follow? I created `app` symlink and have it pointed to `mylaravelapp/public`

Comment: Another tricks maybe, just load the font-awesome css and fonts via `CDN`

Comment: Do you have the view file where you are loading the fontawesome file?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Laravel Mix? If so, use the following to change your public path.

```
mix.setPublicPath('app');
```